# How to properly name native functions when using the NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to run my application, but whenever I make a call to a native function it gives me an error and the program crashes. I'm sure it has to do with how I am naming something either in Java or in C.

Here is my call to the functions in Java :

```
package my.commander;

public class RelayAPIModel {

    public static class NativeCalls {

        static {
            System.loadLibrary( "RelayAPI");
        }

        public native static byte InitRelayJava();

        public native static void FreeRelayJava();
    }
```

Here are the functions in the `.c` file:

```
void Java_my_commander_RelayAPIModel_FreeRelayJava( JNIEnv * env, jobject this ) {
    RelayAPI_DataValid = 0;
    RelayAPI_SetBaud = 0;
    RelayAPI_get = 0;
    RelayAPI_put = 0;
    RelayAPI_flush = 0;
    RelayAPI_delay = 0;
    RelayAPI_initilized = 0;
}


BYTE Java_my_commander_RelayAPIModel_InitRelayJava( JNIEnv *env, jobject obj  ) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Here they are in the `.h` file :

```
void Java_my_commander_RelayAPIModel_FreeRelayJava( JNIEnv * env, jobject obj );

BYTE Java_my_commander_RelayAPIModel_InitRelayJava( JNIEnv *env, jobject obj );
```

Here is my `LogCat:`

```
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: InitRelayJava
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170):    at my.eti.commander.RelayAPIModel$NativeCalls.InitRelayJava(Native Method)
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170):    at my.eti.commander.MainMenu.initMain(MainMenu.java:241)
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170):    at my.eti.commander.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:81)
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-01 09:58:21.933: E/AndroidRuntime(17170):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I would like to clarify now, that I have tried changing the C method names to `Java_my_commander_RelayAPIModel_NativeCalls_FreeRelayJava` and `Java_my_commander_RelayAPIModel_NativeCalls_InitRelayJava`. The application still failed to launch and this was the LogCat for that:

```
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: InitRelayJava
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441):    at my.eti.commander.RelayAPIModel$NativeCalls.InitRelayJava(Native Method)
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441):    at my.eti.commander.MainMenu.initMain(MainMenu.java:241)
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441):    at my.eti.commander.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:81)
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-01 11:22:10.735: E/AndroidRuntime(17441):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

---

Now, I think that the error lies in the code above. If you all think there is nothing wrong with it, I'm going to add some more information down here just in case the problem lies elsewhere.

This application that I'm creating, uses the functions above to call a library that has been being used for a while. This library was previously used to call functions in a Palm Pilot program which utilize the Palm's bluetooth capabilities. Since Android devices have different bluetooth libraries/capabilities, I am adding code to the native library to call BACK to the java code, to access the Android device's bluetooth capabilities. I do not want to post all of the code pertaining to this here, but if someone feels that it needs to be posted I will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message says it's at:

```
my.eti.commander.RelayAPIModel$NativeCalls.InitRelayJava (Native Method)
```

So make sure that:

- the `native` method declaration is indeed inside the `RelayAPIModel` class, not insude the `RelayAPIModel.NativeCalls` nested class.
- the package name on Java side is `my.commander` as opposed to `my.eti.commander`

EDIT: or you can fix that on the C side. If you want to create native methods in the nested class, the proper name for it would be:

```
Java_my_commander_RelayAPIModel_00024NativeCalls_InitRelayJava()
```

The 00024 is the code of the $ character, which is the nested class delimiter in Java internals. Also, the meaning of the of second parameter (`jobject Obj`) will be different - instead of `this` pointer/class pointer for `RelayAPIModel`, it will be the one for the `RelayAPIModel.NativeCalls`. You won't be able to use it to resolve/call methods in the `RelayAPIModel`.

Comment: Can I not nest the method declaration within a nested class? The `my.eti.commander` error I fixed

Comment: Then the function name on the C side should be `Java_my_commander_RelayAPIModel_00024NativeCalls_InitRelayJava`. The 00024 is the code of the $ character, which is the nested class delimiter in Java internals. Source: [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1550251). Also, the meaning of the of second parameter (`jobject Obj`) will be different.

Comment: Sure. It's the class that your C functions logically belong to.

Comment: In your edit, you say I will not be able to resolve/call methods in the `RelayAPIModel`, but I can still resolve/call methods within `RelayAPIModel.NativeCalls` correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. Also, I've answered your next question. Dude, just hire someone with past C and JNI experience.

Comment: Ha, I'm an intern with no C/JNI experience. I appreciate the thought though.

Answer (score 5):

You can use javah to generate a .h file with the correctly named native files:

```
javah -jni -classpath bin/classes com.example.app.MyClass
```

Comment: Hm, I'll give it a shot but are you sure that's what I want to do? My `.c` file is thousands of line long and the `.h` file was already there with it. All I've done is added these two functions, I don't need to generate an entire file, just the two method headers.

Comment: It will generate a .h for you in the root folder of the project. You don't need to replace your existing .h; just use it to see exactly how to name the functions.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. How am I sure that my `.h` won't be replaced? Do I specify the name anywhere in the `javah` command?

Comment: See [here](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html) for an example of using javah..

Comment: Following his example in the tutorial, still telling me `Error: Could not find class file for ......` From my bin folder, I call `javah -jni my.commander.RelayAPIModel.NativeCalls`, I also tried the call without `NativeCalls` at the end. Your answer is slightly different than what he said to do, but I'm not sure from where I should be calling this. Also, not sure of `-classpath`